# Edit Win32 combo box items

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a combo box with a list of names that are editable through a text box on the same form. How would I go about editing the items that are sitting in the combo box when the user changes the name in the text box? There doesn't seem to be any message to update the strings sitting inside the combo box.

Thanks,

Edit: this is the code thats called when the text changes

```
void txtNameChange(HWND hDlg)
{
    if(SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        wchar_t Name[255];      
        GetDlgItemText(hDlg, txtName, Name, 255);
        //need to set the item text of an item at a certain index here
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rename an item in place. You need to delete the item you wish to modify with the `CB_DELETESTRING` message, and then insert the new value with the `CB_INSERTSTRING` message.